# What is the difference between using WCF Routing (.Net 4.0) and IIS7 Load Balancing (Application Request Routing)?

Tags: wcf, iis, load-balancing

WCF Routing has possibility to manage load balancing and failover, but I have read that it shouldn't be used for this purpose

What is the difference between using **WCF Routing** feature(.Net 4.0) and **IIS7 Load Balancing** (Application Request Routing module)?